# Best hosting option to start with for both dynamic website and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, hosting

As a frontend engineer and where the freelance market seems to be, I'd like to dig into some WordPress stuff and build one for myself to at least know how to play around with it. And soon later I'll dig into backend and probably would deploy a dynamic website.
I'd like to find an option for a way that could host both, and also I can learn and develop more in such hosting method.
I tried heroku but its policy changed so the current way I forked on GitHub wouldn't be available soon. I cancelled bluehost subscription cause I believe it's not gonna be suitable for future deployment with dynamic website.
I've seen aws but its services are too many that I have no where to start with.
I'm so confused with all hosting options and iaas paas saas even tho I tired to read articles to understand them. Plus information online is like crazy a lot so that I have no idea which should I start with.
I am fine with paid service,
Could anyone share some experience with me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just getting started with web hosting you should use firebase hosting (You can't host Wordpress sites in firebase). It is completely free for hosting and also has a free database. You can deploy react.js apps or basic html,css,js websites in firebase. If you are using next.js you can check out Vercel. After exploring all of these you should try to get into the fun stuff such as Hostinger, WP Engine, DigitalOcean which support wordpress, static sites and dynamic sites.

I am not an experienced engineer like you are, but I have used these and trust me they are worth it. I hope this answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

Or you could setup your own server like xampp or wampp and host your sites on your own server